# Put subthread for acquiring a value in UITableViewCell, while displaying the rest of the data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xcode6

I have 4 UILabels in my UITableViewCell. 2 of the UILabels should be filled with data acquired from a URL. When put the call for it in "cellWillDisplay" method, it takes too much time to load the cells. What I hope to do here is, load the UITableView first with the available data and put a Activity Indicator at the other two cells and call the APIs as a subthread. Is it possible to do something like this? If so, how should I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dispatch_queue_t queueName = dispatch_queue_create("queueName", NULL);
dispatch_async(queueName, ^{

     NSString *YOUR_TEXT_FOR_LABEL_1;
     NSString *YOUR_TEXT_FOR_LABEL_1;
     NSString *YOUR_TEXT_FOR_LABEL_1;
     NSString *YOUR_TEXT_FOR_LABEL_1;

      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

       cell.label1.text=YOUR_TEXT_FOR_LABEL_1;
       cell.label2.text=YOUR_TEXT_FOR_LABEL_2;
       cell.label3.text=YOUR_TEXT_FOR_LABEL_3;
       cell.label4.text=YOUR_TEXT_FOR_LABEL_4;

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do a `conditional service call` based on the index of cell in `cellWillDisplay` method. With conditional loading what I mean is,

- lets say you have 4 cells & you want first two of them to be loaded with defaults values & rest 2 of them should be showing activity Indicator. In this case you should have your methods to be modified as :

  ```
  if(indexPath.row < 2) {
      // show preloaded data
  }else {
      // show indicators // call the web-service // dismiss indicators only when you have loaded the data .
  }
  ```
- lets say you have 4 UILables in a Cell. You want first two of them to be loaded with defaults values & rest 2 of them should be showing activity Indicator. In this case you should have your `UILabel` in `UITableViewCell` tagged with some tag values. (May be like some integer tag value).
- Now in the `cellWillDisplay` method, you have to access the views in the  `[cell.contentView subviews]` by the tag value, set previously during the time you created the cell. Now do the conditional web service call to load values for specific ITEM & update it.

  ```
  for(UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews){
      if((view.tag == 300]||(view.tag ==400] ) {
      // call respective web-service & update it
      }else {
      // do nothing
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: One UITableViewCell has 4 UILabels.

Comment: Yea, I have updated my answer. Tag values alike 300 & 400 is for those labels for which I would like to have the web service call.